# Difference between fspecial('sobel') and edge(i,'sobel') matlab

Tags: matlab

I am currently doing an assignment and I am between these two way of calling `sobel` operator.

One is `fil = fspecial('sobel'); h = imfilter(image,fil);`

And the second one is `im = edge(image , 'sobel') ;`

The effect of the second one is much expected, it shows the edges in a more pronounced way, while I am unable to grasp what the first one is doing.

Comment: @Cole"Cole9"Johnson : I am in the middle of doing an assignment , this question is not the homework , but it is a part of the homework .

Answer (score 2):

Not an expert at edge detection, but looking at the MATLAB documentation for [EDGE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/edge.html) and [FSPECIAL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/fspecial.html) shows that `fspecial('sobel')` generates a 3-by-3 filter that emphasizes *horizontal* edges, and that you should transpose it to emphasize *vertical* edges.  On the other hand, EDGE appears to use a more general-purpose algorithm.  That *could* explain why the results from EDGE look more like what you expected.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that , I am experimenting on various orientation for fspecial , let me see whether I can match one with the other one .